# Can an IMAP account use add-ins in Outlook on the window desktop?

Tags: outlook, imap, outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

I failed to get the add-on with the IMAP account in the window environment, and the get add-on is gray

I used the same IMAP account to test Outlook under the windows and mac environments, and found that the add-in can be used on the mac, but the add-on cannot be loaded and obtained on the window。

[mac](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IKjqS.png)
[window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j5qoE.png)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, web addins can only be used against an Exchange account.
If you want your addin to work against any store (PST, IMAP4, OST, etc.), you'd need to create a COM (or VSTO) addin (which only works in desktop Windows version of Outlook).

Answer (score 0):

Outlook web add-ins work for Exchange accounts only. In case of Office 365 you are dealing with Exchange online. The Exchange back-end side is the required part of running web add-ins. You will not find web add-ins when dealing with IMAP or SMTP accounts in Outlook.

For that reason you need to pay attention to the requirement sets supported by the client application and the Exchange server which could also apply restrictions to the features supported.

If you need to support IMAP or SMTP accounts in Outlook you may consider creating a VSTO add-in instead (a COM based add-in) which can be run on Windows only (for desktop applications excluding the new Outlook). See [Walkthrough: Create your first VSTO Add-in for Outlook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/walkthrough-creating-your-first-vsto-add-in-for-outlook?view=vs-2022) for more information.